# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in update users

Tags: mysql

I always receive an "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" message in using update.

```
UPDATE users SET alumni_stat='Not Tracked', position_level='', current_position='', company_name='', date_started='', date_ended='', quarter='', modified_date='';
```

this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bio` text NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` text NOT NULL,
  `cover_pic` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alt_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alumni_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `alumni_stat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `position_level` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `current_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_started` date NOT NULL,
  `date_ended` date NOT NULL,
  `quarter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and this is the create after update trigger on that table

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `employment_history` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.company_name <> NEW.company_name OR OLD.current_position <> NEW.current_position THEN
    INSERT INTO history (id, firstname, lastname, alumni_stat, position_level, current_position, company_name, date_started, date_ended, quarter, modified_date) SELECT (old.id, old.firstname, old.lastname, old.alumni_stat, old.position_level, old.current_position, old.company_name, old.date_started, old.date_ended, old.quarter, old.modified_date) FROM users WHERE old.position_level !='';
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: yes, there is an after update trigger. Is that the reason why?

Comment: Possible. [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statement of the table and the `CREATE` statement of the trigger.

Comment: Is there also an `INSERT` trigger on `history`?

Comment: I already edited it. I hope you could help me with it. Btw, I'm new here.

Comment: There's no other triggers than that. That's the only trigger I have

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce this. Can you also provide `INSERT` statements with some sample data for the table? Maybe that does the trick. And the version of MySQL you're using? The only thing that's at least not good in your statement is that you try to set `date` to empty strings. But that throws a different error. Preferably use `NULL`.